# Which is the best translation for Shankracharya and Ramajuncharya commentary on Upnishads?

Tags: upanishads, adi-shankaracharya, ramanujacharya, book-recommendation

Which is the best translation for Shankracharya and Ramajuncharya commentary on Upnishads?

I would prefer both hindi or English though I would prefer hindi more .

Comment: Ramanuja Idk but Shankaracharya best Hindi you can get with Gita press Upanishads. Gita press is the authentic one for almost everything.. link: [ishadi 9 upanishad](https://gitapressbookshop.in/1421-ईशादि-नौ-उपनिषद्-ishadi-nau-upanishad-?search=Ishadi)

Comment: Ramanujacharya didn't write a commentary on the Upanishads.

Comment: "Which is the best" makes it opinion based.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shankaracharya commentary on Upanishads can be studied here in English : [1](https://estudantedavedanta.net/Eight-Upanisads-Vol-1.pdf), [2](https://estudantedavedanta.net/Eight-Upanisads-vol2.pdf)

Ramanujacharya didnt write commentary on Upanishads but his disiple Ranga Ramanuja Acharya wrote commentaries which can be read here : [3](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Jp9YCHQlVCDnr2zRUM-NgFmssgGK1IgQ/view)

Comment: Sethuji have you tried Gitapress? They mostly sell in other languages too

Comment: No @Archit Ji 
My majority sources are from Internet PDF
Majority are from Ramakrishna Math.
I do have Bhagavadgita Sadhak Sanjeevani and Tattvavivechani in English PDF though. They are wonderful right? But I prefer RK Mutt more..